# No longer able to access the User object in Joomla 3.9.3

Tags: user, joomla-3.9

I built a small website using Joomla 3.4.0./ Wampserver 2.4 on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Now I've upgraded the computer to Windows 10 Pro and Wamp 3.1.7 (64 bit). I've rebuilt the website with latest version of Joomla 3.9.3 from scratch, and it's working fine EXCEPT all those custom modules which access the user object. I haven't changed anything yet. I'm getting errors as below:

> ( ! ) Warning: require_once(C:/wamp64/www\includes\defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\clib\custom\CreateNewAcc.php on line 9
>   Call Stack
>   #    Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0162  404168  {main}( )   ...\CreateNewAcc.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/wamp64/www\includes\defines.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\clib\custom\CreateNewAcc.php on line 9
>   Call Stack
>   #    Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0162  404168  {main}( )   ...\CreateNewAcc.php:0

Each of my custom code files such as 'CreateNewAcc.php' begin like this:

```
<?php
/**/
#uncomment in joomla
$mf1="";
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mf1 = JFactory::getApplication('site');    

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$uname=$user->name;
$uid=$user->id;
$date= JFactory::getDate();    
?>
```

What I have tried:

I've checked the location of defines.php & CreateNewAcc.php files -- they're okay.

Earlier site was in the root of www folder, now it's in a folder of its own named 'elib' (virtual host) within www.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. You will probably need to change `define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]);` to something that points to the root of your Joomla installation. Try something like: `define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..' ));`

Answer (score 1):

Since your `JPATH_BASE` is not `$_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]` anymore thus the required files fail to open.

You can try few things:

1. Comment out the line which  wrongly defines JPATH_BASE on the top of your files. This can handle the error. Since JPATH_BASE is already defined globally.
2. Or Define JPATH_BASE correctly on the top of your files, like: `define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . ‘/elib’ );` - this can also handle the issue.
3. Or better path definition as @Lodder gave in his comment: `define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..' ));`
4. In above PHP 7.0 : `define( ‘JPATH_BASE’, dirname(__DIR__, 1));`

But again, JPATH_BASE does not have to be defined on the top of the files, since JPATH_BASE is defined in `_path_/index.php`. ([reference](https://docs.joomla.org/Constants))